# Conditional type infers type that is too wide when using intersection types

Tags: typescript

Note:

- The code in this question is simplified from more complex production code. This question is *not* about the builder pattern or best practices when overloading methods, but purely about type inference and type compatibility in TypeScript.
- You can find the full code in a [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMglgZ2AIQK5wDYBMICcA8AKgJLAQC2AfFALxQDeAUFFAIZZYAUcZ5AXFBK8AlAIBuAezhYANMzYdOuCGGUIIAO2CtgcCRoEByHhUMyoJ-oNIVRUSdLkt2XZaojqtOvQaiGMiMBmFrwIAkIUANoAunYOsvLyAOYQwJx2EeQxANyMAL65jKCQUAAiIBqs5HAAxvBIaJg4BJnUdPUo6Nh4RDZUUABkDPIuSipqmtq6+kaWAGKsNcASuCDBAGaLy6sC6bTUmXFSCc6KbhNe077+gQtLK2vmm-c7UHs0B30xR475hcXQPpzFZEDqNbq4NqCMFdZpQCAADzIGiwCFggXBzXwcA06zw1l41AA-ASKFABBoIGI8IUcDUMKxlFAavokFByCAYU08AJypVqnUMbCehpUOQAEZ4SiFAD0MqgAFEEZAlhAsBSxZLcIw5VAAIJLVCsDACFiiiX4gA+UAARAEkDaoNbOO9qOatcIiuBAbi8MosLQoECQQCJOt2ZyhdzIbL5YQABaINgIBBwJIaciTKAIeMSVDYDSGYDMiTkMCYCDmcWoYs8KBYCQeRgsjRsshIARciH4d1W2324CO52uqC93DCKEcrvNf4eYAAOlGI4ALAAmYTZKC6hNJzPAXMBmrGjDZ3P5rCF4ssssVqs1kL1xsIRhAA).

The following code defines a type `ListBuilder<TItem>` that works similarly to a `StringBuilder`. Note how the `add()` method supports several overloads, distinguished using the `representation` parameter.

```
type ListBuilder<TItem> = {
  add(item: TItem): void,
  add(representation: 'item', item: TItem): void,
  add(representation: 'list', items: TItem[]): void,
  
  get(): TItem[];
};
```

The type `DynamicListBuilder<TItem>` extends `ListBuilder<TItem>`, adding two more overloads:

```
type DynamicListBuilder<TItem> = ListBuilder<TItem> & {
  add(representation: 'itemFactory', factory: () => TItem): void,
  add(representation: 'listFactory', factory: () => TItem[]): void,
};
```

Now let's add a utility type `ItemFor<TListBuilder>` that gives us the `TItem` type for a given list builder type:

```
type ItemFor<TListBuilder> = TListBuilder extends ListBuilder<infer TItem> ? TItem : never;
```

This utility type doesn't work as expected. The types it infers are too wide:

```
declare const myListBuilder: DynamicListBuilder<number>;

// Expected: number
// Actual:   number | "list" | (() => number)
type Inferred = ItemFor<typeof myListBuilder>;

// This assignment shouldn't compile, but it does
const test: ListBuilder<number | "list" | (() => number)> = myListBuilder;

test.add(() => 42); // This method call shouldn't compile, but it does
```

Why is this? How can I get the `ItemFor<TListBuilder>` type to work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because how you defined `ListBuilder`.

There is a big difference between

```js
type ListBuilder<TItem> = {
  add(item: TItem): void,  
  get(): TItem[];
};
```

AND

```js
type ListBuilder<TItem> = {
  add:(item: TItem) => void,  
  get:() => TItem[];
};
```

First example uses method syntax and methods are bivariant in TypeScript. This is by design. It is for easier migrating from js to ts.

The second example `add:(item: TItem) => void` uses function notation. This is much safer to use arrow function notation than methods.

COnsider this example

```js
type Overloading<T> =
  & ((item: T) => void)
  & ((representation: 'item', item: T) => void)
  & ((representation: 'list', items: T[]) => void)

type ListBuilder<T> = {
  add: Overloading<T>
  get(): T[];
};

type DynamicListBuilder<TItem> = ListBuilder<TItem> & {
  add(representation: 'itemFactory', factory: () => TItem): void,
  add(representation: 'listFactory', factory: () => TItem[]): void,
};

type ItemFor<TListBuilder> = TListBuilder extends ListBuilder<infer TItem> ? TItem : never;

declare const myListBuilder: DynamicListBuilder<number>;

// Expected: number
type Inferred = ItemFor<typeof myListBuilder>;

// Error
const test: ListBuilder<number | "list" | (() => number)> = myListBuilder;

type O<T> = T extends DynamicListBuilder<number> ? true : false
type Result = O<ListBuilder<number | "list" | (() => number)>>

test.add(() => 42);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gbhATgGwPYEMAmBLAdgcwB4AVAPigF4AoKKAMigApHtgIBbALimIEpLycVNky8a9Jo0QQw0gM4RcwdMGypc3AOSsOmgDRQdXHvwqDho8Q2bTZEBUpVqNUTcmxzg%20w23ZzuxADaALqm5iJiVKCQUAAyHsAAQgCu2MiYSCTkFFAA3uJYmNzwSGhYeERk4vgQwIy8ASEA3FQAvi1R4NAAIiC46OzYAMbxnilpGYgkAJK%202XEJ4%20mZxLMc5Az5tIVSMvKKyqrqWkYAYuhDwKiIIN4AZhdXN9z1Ajxr7A1QQiJ6BZiYXZ2ByHZxadyec6Xa63AwPaHPJhhd6%20EJfH6YP7tKidGIfU7XEijJKpZaIebEYlLSZQCAADzYuEwcgWY1Jk0IeDuSBR6ygAH5eewoNxcBAEIgOhkhsh0NIoEN1J4oOwQFT2UhuL1%20oMRosNVNcMl2AAjJCkDoAektUAAonTIJcIEUoEbTUhcdBprhuYhpJhKFB8YTohBUHcVWr9RNzVabba-dcqIrcMq2J5uOqY4bjWbEFAAD5QABEEOAxcLkmRbrzvHmqqzZI6odgWUDxFpDMUzKg2oGw0bHJr5oFUGAiGS0G4D2QCk9UAASvZkshgIGYIRB5lh-mi6WEhWi8xq7mkHXSDj08AAHQ7V5mKAAFgATLwWkA)

`test` has failed, `type Inferred` infered as a `number`.

Try to avoid this syntax: `add(item: TItem): void`.

As you might have noticed, I have overloaded `add` method in other way. Intersection of function produces overloads.

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strict-function-types) you can find more about bivariance

> Under --strictFunctionTypes the first assignment is still permitted if compare was declared as a method. Effectively, T is bivariant in Comparer because it is used only in method parameter positions.

```js
interface Comparer<T> {
  compare(a: T, b: T): number;
}
declare let animalComparer: Comparer<Animal>;
declare let dogComparer: Comparer<Dog>;
animalComparer = dogComparer; // Ok because of bivariance
dogComparer = animalComparer; // Ok
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! You mention that "methods are bivariant in TypeScript. This is by design." Do you have a source for that? It seems a bit arbitrary to me, so I'd like to dig into it a bit.